# Recycler View checkbox/text issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-cardview, android-checkbox

I have 2 problems with my current recycler view with cardview. The first is with the checkbox. The checkboxs  seem to check/uncheck themselves all the time. I know I need to set onCheckedChangeListener, just not sure what to put in it. My second issue is each item in the recycler view/cardview has 4 Strings and 1 checkbox, but sometimes one of the strings is too large, which screws up the whole thing.. Is there any way if a string is too long I can make it make the cardview larger so one of the words will go underneath the first word?

Here is the custom object class:

```
public class Workout{

private String exercise;
private String percent;
private String reps;
private String weight;
private boolean check1;

public Workout(String exercise, String percent, String reps, String weight, boolean check1) {
    this.exercise = exercise;
    this.percent = percent;
    this.reps = reps;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.check1 = check1;
}

/* accessors omitted for readability */

}
```

Here is the adapter:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

Context mContext;
ArrayList<Workout> workout;

public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Workout> workout) {
    mContext = context;
    this.workout = workout;
}
// INITIALIZE HOLDER
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.workout_item, null);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

//BIND DATA TO VIEWS
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Workout objWorkout = workout.get(position);
    holder.exercise.setText(workout.get(position).getExercise());
    holder.percent.setText(workout.get(position).getPercent());
    holder.reps.setText(workout.get(position).getReps());
    holder.weight.setText(workout.get(position).getWeight());
    holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener();

    //LISTENER

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int pos) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, workout.get(pos).getExercise(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return workout.size();
}
}
```

Here is the xml for custom item:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
card_view:cardElevation="10dp" >


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="15dp"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Squat"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtExercise"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="%"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtPercentage"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtExercise"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Reps"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtReps"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Weight"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtWeight"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/check1"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/check1"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/check1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
    android:checked="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For your check box issue:

You need to call `holder.check1.setChecked(boolean)` in the `onBind`. Keep in mind that `onBind` is called several times for each view. So when you scroll, and the recycler view is recycling, it is reusing a checkbox that you aren't specifying if they are checked or not.

Also, because `onBind` is call so frequently it is best to not set the listener there. Set the listener in the constructor of the view holder.

### EDIT

In your listener store the value if it is checked or not. This is usually stored in the object that you are displaying, in your case `workout`. If you don't have a value there for that, you can use [SparseBooleanArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html). It is really good for keeping track of what is checked and not.

---

### For your text issue:

> sometimes one of the strings is too large, which screws up the whole thing

I am not too sure what you mean. But looking at your xml you do a lot things as far as `layout_alignParentTop` or `layout_toLeftOf`. I bet it is something wrong with those once one text is too large. Try changing your root layout to a `LinearLayout` or try to remove as many of those rules as you can. I bet you will discover your bug when doing that.

Comment: Ok thanks I added that and now they aren't randomly checking themselves.. but how do I save that value so when you scroll back up the ones previously checked are still checked? Or is that not possible with recycler view?

Comment: Thanks, will look into SparseBooleanArray. As far as the text issue, it works ok when the strings are small, its just when theyre too large they overlap rather then increasing the height of cardview and putting one word below the other.. I'll see if I can upload a pic  to show it better

Comment: Do as I suggested, and remove those rules until you find the culprit.

Comment: I tried doing that, but then all the checkboxes and textboxes aren't aligned, I need them to all be directly underneath eachother

Comment: I don't recommend doing it as an alternative. Only do it until you find that rule that is breaking it. Then you know what you need to work around. If you can't fix it after that, then you at least know what the problem is and you can ask a specific question. "Fix my bug" questions get a lot more attention than "Find my bug"